# max value in colum for last 10 rows

Tags: python, sqlite

I would like the max value for one column but only for the last 10 rows

```
sqlite3 Accel.db 'SELECT * FROM Acceleration ORDER BY timeTS DESC LIMIT 10;'
```

The above will list the last 10 rows in table Acceleration

```
sqlite3 Accel.db 'SELECT MAX(AccelX) FROM Acceleration;'
```

will list the maximum value in the complete column AccelX

How do i combine the two?
I want the max value in column AccelX for the last 10 rows

for example

```
sqlite3 Accel.db 'SELECT MAX(AccelX) FROM Acceleration ORDER BY timeTS DESC LIMIT 10;'
```

will list the max valve in the complete table/column it does not run the query only on the last 10 rows

Comment: Just to confirm, you are using the term "last 10 rows" interchangeably with "the rows with the 10 smallest values for timeTS", right?

Answer (score 4):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT MAX(AccelX) FROM (
  SELECT AccelX 
  FROM Acceleration 
  ORDER BY timeTS DESC 
  LIMIT 10
)
```

Comment: i have tried the above before and the limit 10 will not restrict the query to only the last 10 rows. the query is run on all the rows in the table

Comment: The subquery limits the rows to the last 10 and the main query gets the MAX of these 10 rows. If you don't get correct results then you don't use it correctly.

Comment: You can check this working demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jfY2FKWtKJxxJ3m6wjacBA/0

Comment: thank it works i tried for hours amazing what a few ( .....) inserted correctly will do thanks again